# ASP.NET MVC 4 changing contents of div without reloading

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I'm new to web development and ASP.NET MVC 4

My question is: Is it possible to replace the content of div tag without needing to refresh the whole page?

If so, what is the best practice of it (best use of MVC 4)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to refresh partial content of a page, you have to use AJAX. There are plenty of resources available online describing how to implement this in ASP.NET MVC. One of the possibilities is using partial views, on which you can find a good tutorial [here](http://www.atlanticbt.com/blog/asp-net-mvc-using-ajax-json-and-partialviews/). However, if you're comfortable with javascript/jQuery a partial view might be overkill if you're just looking to update one div.

Comment: Thanks Glenn, the tutorial really helped.
But performance wise which is better: javascript/jQuery or partial views?

Comment: jQuery will definately be more performant. You can find the documentation here: https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. In order to implement this you can keep your code in the controller, make your jQuery.Ajax() call to url/controllername/actionname and put it in your div using $("#mydiv").append(data.d).

Answer (score 1):

Use javascript and make an ajax call. MVC has a JsonResult for the controller you can use if you like.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure but if I remember right, jQuery is bundled with MVC4. Correct me if I'm wrong.

```
// Javascript code
$('#mydiv').load('/Content/html/mySnippet.html');
```

Would replace the contents of a `<div id="mydiv"></div>` with the contents of the `/Content/html/mySnippet.html`.

You can also call an `action` and return a `partial view` if you wish to have dynamic content instead of a static html template.

Comment: /Content being controller, /html being controller's action and mysnippet.html being the view?